# Pressing Submit button resets values of all fields (Java Script)

Tags: javascript, event-handling, html, innerhtml

When i press Submit button, i need to check the lengths of "First Name" and "Father's Name" texts fields and if they exceed 20 characters, i need to display an error message in front of the text field in red. My code is working fine except that it displays error messages and every thing vanishes in a second. I need error messages to stay there. Here's my java script function :

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate()
        {
            var firstName=document.f1.firname.value;
            var fatherName=document.f1.fname.value;
            var address=document.f1.add.value;
            var phoneNumber=document.f1.ph.value;
            var cnic=document.f1.cnic.value;
            var email=document.f1.email.value;
            var cgpa=document.f1.fname.value;
            var sem=document.f1.sem.value;
            var id=document.f1.cid.value;
            if(firstName.length>20)
            {
                document.getElementById("fin").innerHTML="can't exceed 20 characters!";
            }
            if(fatherName.length>20)
            {
                document.getElementById("fn").innerHTML="can't exceed 20 characters!";
            }
        }
        </script>
</head>
```

The corresponding text fields are :

```
 <form name="f1"  onsubmit="validate()">
    Name : <input type="text" name="firname">  <span id="fin" style="color:red"></span>  <br>
    Father's Name: <input type="text" name="fname"> <span id="fn" style="color:red"></span><br>
</form>
```

Comment: return false from the function if validation fails?

Comment: @NeilThompson what'll happen then? i just want my error message to stay there if validation fails, it vanishes

Comment: where does your submission fire to? maybe it refreshes the page and as an outcome everything resets.

Comment: if the form submits then everything gets reset. If validate returns false when there is a problem (field > 20 chars) then the form does not submit and reset so your validation message is visible

Comment: Thanks it helped, but if i want to show both error meassages at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:(@NeilThompson has mentioned in comments):

```
<form name="f1"  onsubmit="return validate();"> //put return
```

And also put return in your javascript code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
        var flag = true;
        var firstName=document.f1.firname.value;
        var fatherName=document.f1.fname.value;
        var address=document.f1.add.value;
        var phoneNumber=document.f1.ph.value;
        var cnic=document.f1.cnic.value;
        var email=document.f1.email.value;
        var cgpa=document.f1.fname.value;
        var sem=document.f1.sem.value;
        var id=document.f1.cid.value;
        if(firstName.length>20)
        {
            document.getElementById("fin").innerHTML="can't exceed 20 characters!";
            flag = false;
        }
        if(fatherName.length>20)
        {
            document.getElementById("fn").innerHTML="can't exceed 20 characters!";
            flag = false;
        }
        return flag;
    }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: what if i want both error meassages to appear at the same time?

Comment: @Ahmed Please see, I have updated code, which will allow you to show both messages same time, by returning flag at the end of the function.